# laravel socialite logout issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel socialite for login with google and facebook.
After login from admin on the backend, there is one option to log in with Google and Microsoft. if admin will log in from Google or Microsoft then all events related to that account will come and I am displaying those events.
My problem is after log out, it's not getting the log out from Microsoft and Google.

I want if I logged out from admin and again if I will log in from admin, at that time it should not show events which came from before login.

For logout, I am using laravel auth logout method.

Comment: show code for logout method for admin

Comment: in which controller have you added logout method for admin logout ?

Comment: ```<a href="{{ url('admin/logout') }}" >Logout</a>```

Answer (score 2):

Add logout method in your `AdminLoginController`

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->guest(route( '/admin' ));
}
```

Comment: So Auth::logout doesn't do flush and regenerate? Do we need them anyway btw?