# Logout from Github Laravel Socialite

Tags: authentication, github, laravel-7, laravel-socialite

I have made an api in laravel with socialite and github and I need to log out so that the application asks me with which github account I want to log in every time.

Comment: Hi @Ivan Caballero, welcome to SO. I'd suggest being more specific in your question, the way it's phrased now the answer is probably just "yes", and you probably want to know how to implement it. I'd suggest showing some code, your attempts at implementation, what you've found by googling the problem at hand, and being specific about what you're not sure about

Comment: @Ivan Caballero have a look at my response and see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is how to logout from your registered user (which used Github) and destroy the oAuth session of github?

Maybe have a look at this:
[laravel socialite logout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110710/laravel-socialite-logout-issue)

OK.

If you are using socialite, do check the documentation of each provider you use. Probably you should make a GET or a POST request to their service in order to log out the user.

For example, Globus.org uses [this link](https://www.postman.com/) (documentation link) in order for you to log out your users:

> GET https://auth.globus.org/v2/web/logout

Clicking it will log out your user from your service.
Do note that most provider might use similar techniques.

Use [POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com/) to make such requests and experiment (especially when you are trying to register users, making calls with POSTMAN might seem helpful)

Then you are faced with the following issue:

- What type of data did you store on you database? (the next bullet might help you understand what I mean)
- Did you store in some way, the provider name the user used to login to your system?

If so, each provider might use a different way to log out / register a user from your Laravel project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28123327)

Comment: I made some additions. Maybe those will help. @NicoHaase